# How to find a parallel line for a given line segment (both the parallel line which is above and below of my source line) in Java JTS?

Tags: java, geometry, jts

How to find a parallel line for a given line segment (both the parallel line which is above and below of my source line) in Java JTS (**JTS Topology Suite**) ?
Input: I have Points(long & lat) of my source line
coordinate 1(Long, Lat) ---------------------------- coordinate 2(Long, Lat)

Coordinate[] coordinate= new Coordinate(new Coordinate(Long, Lat), new Coordinate(Long, Lat));

Source Line->

```
LineSegment sourceLine =new GeometryFactory().createLineString(coordinate);
```

now I have to find a parallel line to Source Line, above and below it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `pointAlongOffset(double segmentLengthFraction, double offsetDistance)`  method on `LineSegment` for this purpose. Example:

```
// source line from given start and end coordinate
LineSegment sourceLine = new LineSegment(startCoordinate, endCoordinate);

// left from start- to end-point (note negative offset distance!)
Coordinate startLeft = sourceLine.pointAlongOffset(0, -parallelDistance);
Coordinate endLeft = sourceLine.pointAlongOffset(1, -parallelDistance);
LineString leftLine = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{startLeft, endLeft});
// right from start- to end-point (note positive offset distance!)
Coordinate startRight = sourceLine.pointAlongOffset(0, parallelDistance);
Coordinate endRight = sourceLine.pointAlongOffset(1, parallelDistance);
LineString rightLine = new GeometryFactory().createLineString(new Coordinate[]{startRight, endRight});
```

Answer (score 0):

Calculate bearing `B0` in the start point
Rotate bearing by 90 degrees `B01=B0+90` and get point `P01` at needed distance with bearing `B1`
Do the same for the end point (note that bearing slightly differs), get point `P11`. `PO1-P11` is the first line

Do the same for bearing roteted by `-90`, build the second line

[Here are formulas](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get bearing and point with given distance and bearing